# Solving Basic System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm attempting to find the solution to the following system of differential equations, and when my solution doesn't match [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bdx%2Fdt%3D5x-4y,%20dy%2Fdt%3Dx%7D), and I'm stuck on why.

$\frac{dx}{dt}=5x-4y$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=x$

First, I attempt to solve the linear DE by elimination:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=5x-4y -> Dx-5x+4y=0$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=x -> Dy-x=0$

Multiple the 1st by D and the 2nd by 4 and then subtract

$D^2x-5Dx+4Dy=0$

$4Dy-4x=0$

=$D^2x-5Dx+4x=0$

Solve for the roots, 1,4, and I should have my first equation of $x(t)=c_1e^t+c_2e^4t$.

I think I took a long way to find y:
Multiplied the 2nd equation by D and then substituted in for Dx from the first equation and the fact that I know x=Dy
$D^2y-Dx=0 ->  D^2y-(5x-4y) ->D^2y-5Dy+4y$

$y(D^2-5D+4)$

Again the roots are 4 and 1: $y(t)=c_3e^{4t}+c_4e^t$

Since I should only have two constants of integration, I can plug everything back into the 2nd equation of Dy=x:
$4c_3e^{4t}+c_4e^t=c_1e^{4t}+c_2e^t$
And now determine my coefficients in terms of $c_1$ and $c_2$

$e^{4t}(4c_3-c_1)+e^t(c_4-c_2)=0$

$c_3=\frac{1}{4}c_1$ and $c_4=c_2$

Replacing with this and I now have:
$x(t)=c_1e^{4t}+c_2e^t, y(t)=\frac{1}{4}c_1e^{4t}+c_2e^t$ which looks nothing like Wolfram. 
Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is Wolfram solution?

Comment: Linked it, but $x(t)=\frac{1}{3}c_1e^t(4e^{3t}-1)-\frac{4}{3}c_2e^t(e^{3t}-1)$ and $y(t)=\frac{1}{3}c_1e^t(e^{3t}-1)-\frac{1}{3}c_2e^t(e^{3t}-4)$

Comment: I can't see many differences: the solutions are composition of two exponentials and the coefficient of $e^{-4t}$ for y is one fourth of the one of x. Costants may differ in their expression according to the solution processo, this is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from $$x'=5x-4y$$ we get $$x''=4x'-4y'$$ and with $$y'=x$$ we get  $$x''=5x'-4x$$ with the solution $$\left\{\left\{x(t)\to c_1 e^t+c_2 e^{4 t}\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: Good approach. Same end solution I too got, but how come it differs so much from Wolfram Alpha?

Answer (score 0):

To solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
x'(t)=5x(t)-4y(t)\\
y'(t)=x(t)
\end{cases}
$$

Use Laplace transform:

$$
\begin{cases}
s\text{X}(s)-x(0)=5\text{X}(s)-4\text{Y}(s)\\
s\text{Y}(s)-y(0)=\text{X}(s)
\end{cases}
$$

So, we get for $\text{X}(s)$ and $\text{Y}(s)$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{X}(s)=\frac{x(0)-4\text{Y}(s)}{s-5}\\
\text{Y}(s)=\frac{\text{X}(s)+y(0)}{s}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, substitute them into eachother to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{X}(s)=\frac{sx(0)-4y(0)}{s^2-5s+4}\\
\text{Y}(s)=\frac{x(0)+y(0)(s-5)}{s^2-5s+4}
\end{cases}
$$

And with inverse Laplace transform, we find:

$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=\frac{e^t\left(4e^{3t}\left(x(0)-y(0)\right)-x(0)+4y(0)\right)}{3}\\
y(t)=\frac{e^t\left(e^{3t}\left(x(0)-y(0)\right)-x(0)+4y(0)\right)}{3}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Haven't gotten that far in my studies to have covered Laplace transform

Comment: Ok, this is a way of solving this question. Later I'll ad a different answer, I'm currently not able to improve.